# How to create a Metric Filter for Log Stream in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, aws-lambda, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

This is my log insight query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message

| filter @message like 'share\BIExtracts\wep\'

| sort @timestamp desc

| limit 1
```

I would like create a subscription filter for Lambda using a filter pattern to do same as above, getting the most recent data from this file audit logs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cloudwatch logs can be used to capture the logs and trigger the Lambda function.